# C: Insertion sort logic not working using pointers and structs

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, struct

```
typedef struct record
{   
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    char telephone[20];

}Record;

typedef struct node
{
    Record data;
    struct node *next;
}Node;

Node *head = NULL;

/*
return positive value if *x > *y
return negative value if *x < *y
return 0 if *x == *y
*/
int cmpRecord(const Record* x, const Record* y) {
    if (x->name > y->name) return 1;
    if (x->name < y->name) return -1;
    return 0;
}

void addRecord(Record x)
{
    Node *previousNode = NULL;
    Node *newNode;
    Node *n;

    newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = x;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)  // The list is empty
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else       // The list is not empty
    {
        n = head;
        while (n->next != NULL)
        {
            if ((cmpRecord(&n->data.name, &newNode->data.name) < 0) && (cmpRecord(&n->next->data.name, &newNode->data.name) > 0)) // Insertion Sort
            {
                // We have to put it between these 2 nodes
                newNode->next = n->next;
                n->next = newNode;
                return;
            }

            else
            {
                previousNode = n;
                n = n->next;
            }
        }
            n->next = newNode;

     }

}
```

So this code is supposed to add records of people in a list and sort them alphabetically according to the Name. However when displaying the list, the items are not in alphabetical order. What seems to be the problem?  Thanks
PS. The cmpRecord is used in the if-statement for the insertion sort.

Comment: You cannot sort strings alphabetically using `>` and `<`. You are only comparing the value of the pointers the string decays to.

Answer (score 0):

To compare two string alphabetically, use `strcmp()`:

```
int cmpRecord(const Record* x, const Record* y) {
    int cmp = strcmp(x->name, y->name);
    return (cmp > 0) - (cmp < 0);
}
```

and call this function by `cmpRecord(&n->data, &newNode->data);`, because the `data` field has type `Record`.